# Adjusting a pre-made normal map inside node editor on the fly?

Tags: materials, node-editor, normals, normal-map

Is it possible to set up a node layout for a pre-made normal map with an alpha channel that can break up the black and white channels so that they can be adjusted to add or lower height for different parts of the image? Or is there a better way to achieve this inside the material nodes?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please could you provide additional detail, screenshots, examples, etc. of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you try using the normal map node (you can set the strength there)?